# Data in DatagridView is not refreshed automaticly

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

i have a datagridview displaying all my user in sql server database.
and this little code is for painting rows of disabled user (to disable an user i have just to click on a checkbox)
the color doesn't refresh automaticly after checking or unchecking checkboxes and i have to clic somewhere in the form or in another cell to have the changes visible.
can i make them visible just after checking or unchecking.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        string userid = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        if (e.ColumnIndex > 7)
        {
            bool value = Convert.ToBoolean(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value);
            string colname = dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderText.ToString();

            obj.updatePlugins(colname, value, userid);
        }
        if (e.ColumnIndex >= 6 && e.ColumnIndex <= 7)
        {
            bool adm = Convert.ToBoolean(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value);
            string colname = dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderText.ToString();
            obj.updateAdmin(adm, userid, colname);
        }
        if (e.ColumnIndex < 6)
        {
            string value = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();
            string colname = dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderText.ToString();
            obj.updateUser(colname, value, userid);
        }

        FillData1();
    }
```

private void dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
        {

```
        if (e.ListChangedType != ListChangedType.ItemDeleted)
        {
            DataGridViewCellStyle red = dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.Clone();
            red.BackColor = Color.Red;
            DataGridViewCellStyle white = dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.Clone();
            white.BackColor = Color.White;

            foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                if (Convert.ToBoolean(r.Cells["DisabledUsers"].Value))
                {

                    r.DefaultCellStyle = red;
                    for (int i = 6; i < r.Cells.Count; i++)
                    {
                        r.Cells[i].Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
                        r.Cells[8].Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    r.DefaultCellStyle = white;
                    for (int i = 6; i < r.Cells.Count; i++)
                    {
                        r.Cells[i].Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
                        r.Cells[8].Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
                    }
                }
            }


        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried dataGridView1.Refresh() or .Invalidate()?

Comment: yes tried, no success